Which festival was Moses refering to in Exodus 10:9?
Exodus 10:9 NIV

Moses answered, “We will go with our young and our old, with our sons and our daughters, and with our flocks and herds, because we are to celebrate a festival to the Lord.”


Exodus 10:9 says

וַיֹּאמֶר מֹשֶׁה בִּנְעָרֵינוּ וּבִזְקֵנֵינוּ נֵלֵךְ בְּבָנֵינוּ
וּבִבְנוֹתֵנוּ בְּצֹאנֵנוּ וּבִבְקָרֵנוּ נֵלֵךְ כִּי חַג־יְהֹוָה לָנוּ

Bolded means "for it is a chag (festival) of Hashem for us", the chag refers to Shavuot which commemorates the giving of Torah at Sinai. It is not the festival of Passover since the passover was celebrated inside the land of Egypt. It's also not Sukkot since that is not connected with Sinai or the giving of the Torah.
Shavuot occurs in the month of Sivan and the Torah teaches that “in the third month after the Exodus of the Children of Israel from Egypt they arrived in the desert of Sinai”. The day mentioned was 1 Sivan, and after five days the decalogue was given.

Perfect! It is the spring harvest festival, symbolizing God's gathering of His people.

"It is not the festival of Passover since the passover was celebrated inside the land of Egypt." — Not necessarily. Moses could have been referring to (a form of) Passover (perhaps celebrating Isaac's near sacrifice). But since they weren't allowed to leave for this festival, it ended up being celebrated (for real) inside Egypt this one year.

Upvoted but... The more I think about it, the more I believe that Shavuot refers to  feast of Ex 10.9 rather than the other way around. This is an important distinction. Shavuot means "weeks" ... but how could they go through the weeks of counting the omer if they did not grow crops? In other words, I think that Shavuot came to be associated with this feast, but the feast was not yet Shavuot.

I upvoted Avi's answer because it conforms to traditional Jewish understandings of the issue. However, I would add another possibility, namely that this was not specifically Shavuot, because Moses did not yet know of that holiday, nor could the Israelites perform the necessary preparations for it. Moreover, there are other possibilities.
We get a clue about this feast, later on right after the episode of the Golden Calf. Exodus 32:

So when Aaron saw it, he built an altar before it. And Aaron made a
proclamation and said, “Tomorrow is a feast to the Lord.” 6 Then they
rose early on the next day, offered burnt offerings, and brought peace
offerings; and the people sat down to eat and drink, and rose up to
play.

This implies that a feast was planned for the very day when Moses came down from the mountain. No earlier feast is mentioned.  Although the timing of this feast roughly dovetails with the Shavuot hypothesis,  it is difficult to think that this sacred holiday was instituted by Aaron in association with the Golden Calf. Yet this is the first feast that the Israelites celebrated in the wilderness. Moreover, other dating scenarios have been presented for Aaron's feast, such as the idea that it was a New Moon festival later associated with Pentecost/Shavuot. The argument is that this holiday could not be celebrated yet, because it requires passing through the period of the counting of the omer (sheaf-offerings). This could not be done in the wilderness, since the Israelites did not grow crops at that time.
Conclusion: The feast of 10:9 may indeed have been known later as Shavuot. However, there are other possibilities, such as a New Moon festival or some unspecified feast. It would be impossible for the Israelites  to celebrate Shavuot as such because to do so they had to pass through the period of the counting of the omer first. All we can say for certain is that it was as God described it in Ex. 5:1:

Moses and Aaron went to Pharaoh and said, “Thus says the Lord, the God
of Israel: Let my people go, that they may hold a feast for me in the
wilderness.”


Aren't Pentecost and Shavuot names for the the same thing? It sounds like you're saying they are different events.

@RayButterworth ... Yes. I said Pentecost because this emphasizes  the "counting of the omer" - something that could not be done until after there were sheaves to offer, an impossibility during the wilderness period.  But thanks for the feedback. I'll update my answer to make it less confusing.

I did some research and discovered it was referred to as the Spring harvest Festival, a name predates both Shavuot and Pentecost

This makes sense in light of what I argued above, but in terms of Ex 10:9  this means they would need to store offerings from the spring harvest when they left very suddenly during the Passover event, fled from Pharaoh, crossed the sea, traveled to the mountain, and then waited 40 more days before the feast. So it would be a spring harvest festival with no perishable foods from the spring harvest.

"In the third month after the Israelites’ departure from the land of Egypt, on the first day, they came to the wilderness of Sinai." (Ex 19.1)  They were already living on quail and manna, so apparently not much left in the way of the spring harvest.
